# Is there a service similar to the Google+ Feedback Tool?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am looking for the same functionality as the Google+ Feedback - Tool provides (that is: a button which I can somehow put on my page to get screenshots from my customers)

Does anybody know such a library / service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our start up http://www.usersnap.com offers such a service, it's free for small sites.
You can install it by adding a short piece of JavaScript to your page (like the Google Analytics snippet).